# Choose the rows with special conditions in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, I want to choose the rows which their average value for column **val1** until **val4** is greater than 1 and the number of zeros for the row is not greater than 1.
For example, in the following df:

```
    id  val0  val1  val2  val3  val4
0  100     5     0     0     0     0
1  200    50   -10    10   -10    10
2  300     3     0     1     1     1
3  400     4     0     3     2     5
4  500     5     3     7     0     9
5  800     3     1     0     0     6

data = {'id': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 800],
 'val0': [5, 50, 3, 4, 5, 3],
 'val1': [0, -10, 0, 0, 3, 1],
 'val2': [0, 10, 1, 3, 7, 0],
 'val3': [0, -10, 1, 2, 0, 0],
 'val4': [0, 10, 1, 5, 9, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**row 0:** has 4 zeros, so we don't consider this row.

**row 1:** the average from val1-val4 is 0, we don't consider that.

**row 2:** the average from val1-val4 is 0.75, we don't consider that.

**row 3:** we consider that. Since two conditions are satisfied.

**row 4:** we consider that. Since two conditions are satisfied.

**row 5:** we have 2 zeros, so we don't consider that. The desired output is:

```
    id  val0  val1  val2  val3  val4
3  400     4     0     3     2     5
4  500     5     3     7     0     9
```

Comment: I modified your desired output because row 2's average is 0.75. If you want a different condition that does include row 2, go ahead and update your question.

Comment: A lot of what you're trying to do would make more sense/be simpler if 0's were NaNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IUUC, you can use `df.filter(regex='val[1-4]')` to filter the columns that contians `val1-4` and use `mean(axis=1)` and `sum(axis=1)` to operate on columns.

```py
val = df.filter(regex='val[1-4]')
df = df[val.mean(axis=1).gt(1) & df.eq(0).sum(axis=1).le(1)]
```

```
print(df)

    id  val0  val1  val2  val3  val4
3  400     4     0     3     2     5
4  500     5     3     7     0     9
```

Comment: Thank you. I also have one question, val.mean(axis=1) is the average over all columns? since I want the average from val1 column until val 4. I just updated the dataframe in question. Could you please take a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: @Sadcow Yes, `val.mean(axis=1)` is the average over all columns.

Comment: OP explicitly stated that they did not want `val0` to be included in the first condition.

Comment: @BeRT2me Didn't notice that, fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
df[df[['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']].mean(axis=1).gt(1) & df.eq(0).sum(axis=1).le(1)]
```

Output:

```
    id  val0  val1  val2  val3  val4
3  400     4     0     3     2     5
4  500     5     3     7     0     9
```